# Using DropDownLists to constrain and select Model values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-validation

I have a model for customer

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string CustomerName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    // Cont..
}
```

When I post the customer creation form to `public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)` which is an action in my `CustomerController`, it produce error against `ModelState`. For example... if my code is like below..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
{
    customer.Title = "Mr"; // This is what I set for ensuring the field has value

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Code to save customer entity
    }
    // else..
}
```

In my MVC view it show the error in Customer Title

for instance, if I remove the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` portion from the code above, the customer entity is saved fine and I can see the record in database.

What might be the issue here?

## EDIT :

passing Customer Titles as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

```
ViewData["CustomerTitles"] = GetCustomerTitles();
```

Code in view

```
div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownList("CustomerTitles")%>
    <br /><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title) %>
</div>
```

Comment: Are all RequiredValue(s) filled?

Comment: of course, all values are filled and I can see them in DB as well after I removed the validation portion. Validation only show me the error against Customer.Title, which I am already providing directly above the validation checkpoint.

Comment: ModelState.IsValid is set at the point that the controller action is called. Assigning a "title" field after this event will not change the IsValid flag. Please could you post the View code as well?

Comment: @BlueBird If it isn't filled before POST then it will set the IsValid flag to `false`.

Comment: @BlueBird What is the error shown in your view ?

Comment: @LewsTherin mhh.. YOu might be correct. I have a DropDownList for titles. I pass the dropdownlist through ViewData. In post, I need to read the value of it and assign back. This is the cycle. How can I solve this dear?

Comment: View code added @RichardA.

Comment: Okay, I now know what the problem is, but it'll be a while before I can post the solution. You need to use a DropDownListFor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("Title", new SelectList(ViewData["CustomerTitles"]), Customer.Title.ToString()) %>
```

This should hopefully pass the title in as a string, which is what your Model is asking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could grab the idea from your above code. I simply change my ViewData["CustomerTitles" to ViewData["Title"] and replace the name of DropDownList in view from "CustomerTitles" to "Titles". Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I learnt the answer for this question from the reply of @Richard A.
I did some modification to my code and it works fine.

I post it below, so might help some one.

ViewData from Controller

```
ViewData["Title"] = GetCustomerTitles(customer.Title);
```

View

```
<div class="editor-field">
  <%: Html.DropDownList("Title") %>
  <br /><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title) %>
</div>
```

The Idea is.. in Entity, the field name is "Title". After the form is posted, compiler check for a HTML element having the name "Title" and assign its value. If it is not present, it set the value of `ModelState` to false.